# Как получить дополнительные колонки с условием во время SELECT? Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица:

| XYZ |
| --- |
| 12 |
| 32 |
| 24 |
| 12 |
| 5 |
| 3 |
| 13 |

А нужно получить:

| XYZ | color1 | color2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | red | red |
| 32 | green | green |
| 24 | green | red |
| 12 | red | red |
| 5 | red | red |
| 3 | red | red |
| 13 | red | red |

color1(Если XYZ>20, то green, иначе red)

color2(Если XYZ>30, то green, иначе red)

Как получить колонки color1 и color2 во время SELECT?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE

Comment: @Akina, спасибо!)